# How to update the input[type=number] quantity field using custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, code

I have written this code which works perfectly fine in CodePen, to update the value of an input[type='number'] field on my single product listing page. The reason for doing so is to have completely restyled number input, to match the styling requirements by the client. The problem is its not working on Wordpress.

the code is

```html
<script>
    const counter = document.querySelector(".qty, input[type=number]");
const plusBtn = document.getElementById("increase-qty");
const minusBtn = document.getElementById("decrease-qty");


let countValue = counter.value;
let count = 0;

counter.addEventListener ("change", (e)=> {
  countValue = e.target.value;
})

function increment() {
  count ++;
  countValue = count;
  counter.value = countValue;
  alert(`The new count is ${countValue}`)
}

function decrease() {
  if (count === 0){
    countValue = count;
  } else {
      count --;
      countValue = count;
      counter.value = countValue;
      alert(`The new count is ${countValue}`)
  }
}

plusBtn.addEventListener("click", increment);
minusBtn.addEventListener("click", decrease);

</script>
```

I have tried it as both an html element with script tags, as shown above, and by inserting it using custom code as part of elementor pro builder.

What am I missing? I am sure the id and the selectors are correct.

a link to the pen is [here](https://codepen.io/wearenv-digital/pen/xxaXWvN)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wearenv-digital/pen/xxaXWvN)

Comment: when you say it's not working on WordPress can you be more specific than that? Do you mean it cant find the input? Or it does but it does the wrong thing? Or it generates JS errors in the browser console? Keep in mind that 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here, as well as generic JS questions, so you can't ask for help with WooCommerce/Elementor or other ecommerce plugins here, and general JS questions go on stackoverflow. Having said that, why is there a comma in `.qty, input[type=number]`? And why not read the value straight from `counter` everytime instead of a listener?

Comment: Okay I apologise, I will repost to SO. The comma is to provide more specificity to the  to code, to ensure the correct element is returned. Ah you are correct, that listener on the counter is not needed, and as I won't be using the pseudo shadow elements to change the value, it is actually redundant. It is in there purely to test that the element value is being read by the code. I will edit the code block to better show that. To answer your first question, apparently the query selector element does not exist, yet it is showing in the DOM.

Comment: that could be a quirk of how Elementor works, what you've done is not how JS is normally added to WordPress. Normally you would put it in a JS file then use `wp_enqueue_script` to add it. The `,` you've used doesn't add specificity it signals you want to attach multiple selectors to a single set of rules in CSS it isn't for specificity e.g. you want to match elements that are ".qty" but you _also_ want to match elements that are `input[type=number]`, which is not what you said you wanted, did you actually mean `input[type=number].qty`?